# TFS + MSSQL continuously loads 30% of CPU

Tags: sql-server, tfs

I found that on my computer the CPU loaded on 30% all time. In the Task Manager I found that MSSQL loads the CPU. It was strange because as I know I didn`t use SQL at that time. I launched the SQL Server Profiler and found that all time used the Tfs_Configuration database.

[image]

It was strange because I didn`t use tfs at that time.
I launch the TFS Admin Console and stop the default collection (it is only one collection) + restart the SQL service. But it nothing changed.

So:

1. Why it happens? Why there are the Tfs_Configuration used all time?
2. How to stop it?

**UPDATE**

Configuration:

- WinServer2012R2Standard
- MS SQL Server 2016 RTM
- TFS 2015 Update 3

TFS installed with defaults (one default collection, etc.)

No I don`t want stop TFS. I want understand why Tfs_Configuration used by MSSQL all time, even when I nothing to do and great loads CPU + I want to fix this issue.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? How's your environment like? Tfs_Configuration stores data that describes your deployment of Team Foundation Server, including the name and location of the other databases. Do you want to stop TFS? You may check event log in Event Viewer to see if there is anything helpful.

Comment: Look at the update abowe. I don`t want to stop TFS. I want to fix abnormal CPU loading (the reason of this loading - abnormal usage Tfs_Configuration database even if I nothing to do). Yes I check the Event Viewer - but nothing helpful found.

Comment: Except one - when I launch the TFS site - it often take a great time to launch (about few minutes). And I see the timeout error in the Event Viewer. I read a lot of information about profiling - but still can`t identify whats wrong with TFS + SQL on my side.

Comment: Sorry :-(.  It's hard for us to troubleshoot performance issue without any error message.

Comment: Have you checked the jobs in the /tfs/_oi/_jobMonitoring page? They run in the background, and some configuration problem there may explain your issue.

Comment: Giulio Vian, no...could you please say where I can check it?

Comment: I get the same problem and I have databases that are not even connected to a TFS yet.  It seems to happen with the databases all by themselves.

Comment: It's been a while since I've looked at TFS on SQL Server but I do recall that it creates a number of sql agent jobs for cleanup/reindexing/full text crawl. If your config database is large you might also want to look at cleanup options described here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/tfs-configuration-database-getting-way-too-large/1272649

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the problem.
.
TFS will put a full text index into the satellite databases.  It will set this full text index to 'auto' for change tracking.   This will cause the server to continuously, on its own, to scan and rebuild the index, even when nothing is happening.  This sql code will cause the index to stop rescanning.

```
use Tfs_<YOUR Collection>
go
exec sp_fulltext_database 'disable'
go
alter fulltext index on WorkItemLongTexts set change_tracking = OFF
```